# own java mail client & yandex smtp server - javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, email, authentication, exception, smtp

evening,

i'm trying to do my own email client and then error came.

im using  `javax.mail`  library

i did try several methods for sending, most of them crash on sad places. anyway, one method i consider with potential is fine until end when message pops up:

`m02 error-2: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Your message looks like spam. You need to use web for sending or prove you are not a robot using the following link http://ya.cc/[deleted]` where [deleted] is originally few letters string.

i saw with gmail, you need to set something in settings to be able to use your own client, i expected this would be similar case but i couldn't find any settings about it in yandex mailbox settings.

another point, smtp address i have found at some forum so i presume it is possible to use own client

properties i set:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port_ssl);
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port_ssl);
```

where

```
private String host = "smtp.yandex.com";
private String port_ssl = "465";
```

other code, im using classic way: `Session` for `Authenticator`, then `Message` and `Transport.send`. anyway, i think problem is with properties or mailbox settins? i just cant think of where.

question: how can i fix it so i can send an email with my client?

note: reason for using yandex is thanks to simple sign up since i dont have phone number and gmail requires one. if you know about other email service where own client should work & no need for phone that is also nice alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, you could try the service https://protonmail.com, it should not require phone number and it can be reachable by SMTP clients using these settings https://mailsettings.co/protonmail-smtp-server-settings